# Authenticate web app as another user for support purposes using OAuth and/or Auth0

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, auth0

Is there any way to allow certain users (perhaps with an `admin` role and appropriate permissions) to authenticate a React app as another user?

The use case would be to allow support staff to authenitcate as another user to see the app as they see it, and debug or help users with their issues.

Thanks!

Comment: #1 Are you using a service like auth0, okta, etc or is an internal development? #2 Are you open to use only the oauth2 spec or maybe an hybrid or customization?

Comment: I've been working on an Auth0 implementation until coming accross this blocker. Open to all other options, including a 'custom' OAuth 2 implementation

Comment: Did Gary Archer answer helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question and a common requirement, but unfortunately can be difficult to implement. Ultimately though this type of solution always involves claims and work in APIs.

**OAUTH STANDARDS**

It is worth keeping an eye on evolving standards such as the [On Behalf Of Flow](https://curity.io/resources/learn/on-behalf-of-flow/), to see if they can help. However, they may not meet your requirements or be supported by your vendor yet.

**AUTHENTICATION**

A support user 'signing in as a business user' is not really right, since users always sign in with their own credentials. In the normal case this may need to an access token containing these claims and a user could only make order changes if their token contains this scope:

- subject: businessUser1
- role: customer
- scope: openid orders

**IMPERSONATION**

In the impersonation case the support person would sign in with their own credentials and may then receive an access token with these claims. You could perhaps use these claims to only allow certain actions to be performed by support users:

- subject: supportUser1
- role: support
- can_impersonate: true
- scope: openid orders

Ideally it would be good to prompt users with the 'can_impersonate' claim at the time of authentication / token issuance. This would involve popping up a screen where the business user could be entered, then included in access tokens and also audited.

**EXTENSIBILITY**

Typically though this would require a [custom authentication action](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/authentication-service-admin-guide/authentication-actions/index.html), which is often needed for more advanced authentication cases. If this is not supported by your provider then you may need to do more work in your apps, such as:

- Invoking a screen after login completes
- Storing the business user in your API data
- Perhaps also auditing the impersonation event in your API data

**2022 UPDATE**

Recently at Curity we have published some detailed articles on impersonation. Anyone wanting to implement this pattern might find them useful:

- [Aproaches](https://curity.io/resources/learn/impersonation-flow-approaches/)
- [Tutorial](https://curity.io/resources/learn/impersonation-implementation/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! Super helpful. Also great to know 'impersonation' is the key word I was looking for